# How to serialize a class that contains a MemoryStream in .NET 7?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, serialization, memorystream

I am currently migrating some old code from .NET framework over to .NET Core 7. I am trying to deserialize a class (that is marked serializable) that contains a MemoryStream from a file.

Class example:

```
[Serializable]
public class quest{
    public MemoryStream inner { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialization Example:

```
var fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
var loaded_data = (quest)bf.Deserialize(fs);
```

According to the documentation for [MemoryStreams][1]:

> If a MemoryStream object is serialized to a resource file it will
> actually be serialized as an UnmanagedMemoryStream. This behavior
> provides better performance, as well as the ability to get a pointer
> to the data directly, without having to go through Stream methods.

But when I try my code, I get the following exception:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type 'System.IO.MemoryStream' in Assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib' is not marked as serializable.

So my question is, what am I doing wrong here? I know using the BinaryFormatter to serialize is not recommended but unfortunately I have to because the files I want to load are already saved in serialized binary format and are unchangeable. Any guidance is greatly apricated!
[1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream?view=net-7.0

Comment: ".NET Core 7" I don't think there is any such thing. Are you using NET Core 3, or NET 7 ? There is an ASP NET Core 7 which is different again.

.NET Core 3 does indeed have the memorystream not marked as serializable. https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2307#issuecomment-379359370

Comment: @Wh1t3rabbit my mistake, I mean .NET 7

Comment: I had the identical issue, need to deserialize .Net 4.5.2 classes that have a stream property.  Resolution was to create a new Memory stream class in the new project and point the deserializer to it.  See https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2307#issuecomment-536311277